# Return value from function with an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

Can someone tell me how to return the value of `status` as the function's return value.

```
function checkUser() {
    var request;
    var status = false;

    //create xmlhttprequest object here [called request]

    var stu_id = document.getElementById("stu_id").value;
    var dName = document.getElementById("dName").value;
    var fileName = "check_user.php?dName=" + dName + "&stu_id=" + stu_id;
    request.open("GET", fileName, true);
    request.send(null);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var resp = parseInt(request.responseText, 10);
            if(resp === 1) {
                alert("The display name has already been taken.");
                status = false;
            }
            else if(resp === 2) {
                alert("This student ID has already been registered");
                status = false;
            }
            else if(resp === 0) {
                status = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

The above function triggers when you hit submit in a registration form (as must be obvious). The problem is, this form submits irrespective of what the response is, and the alert box sometimes shows nothing [blank], sometimes doesn't show at all. However, if I change the ending `status` to `false` manually [i.e. replace `status` with `false`], the correct value shows up in the alert box.

P.S. I'm worse than a noob in javascript, so suggestions on generally improving the code is also welcome.

Comment: You should probably change the title to something like "Return value from function with an Ajax call", since usernames don't have anything to do with the coding problem.

Comment: How does a question from 2009 get closed as a duplicate of a question from 2013? Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `onreadystatechange` won't fire until... wait for it... the state changes. So when you `return status;` most of the time status will not have had time to set. What you need to do is `return false;` always and inside the `onreadystatechange` determine whether you want to proceed or not. If you do, then you submit the form. In short, take the code that handles the return value and instead run it from within the readystatechange handler. You can do this directly:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        var resp = parseInt(request.responseText, 10);
        switch (resp) {
        case 0:
            document.getElementById('myform').submit();
            break;
        case 1:
            alert("The display name has already been taken.");
            break;
        case 2:
            alert("This student ID has already been registered");
            break;
        }
    }
}
return false; // always return false initially
```

or by passing a [continuation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wesdyer/continuation-passing-style) to the function that makes the asynchronous call:

```
function checkUser(success, fail) {
    ...
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var resp = parseInt(request.responseText, 10);
            switch (resp) {
            case 0:
                success(request.responseText);
            case 1:
                fail("The display name has already been taken.", request.reponseText);
                break;
            case 2:
                fail("This student ID has already been registered", request.reponseText);
                break;
            default:
                fail("Unrecognized resonse: "+resp, request.reponseText);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

In addition to this, before the default `return false;` you might want to have some sort of indicator that something is going on, perhaps disable the submit field, show a loading circle, etc. Otherwise users might get confused if it is taking a long time to fetch the data.

#### Further explanation

Alright, so the reason your way didn't work is mostly in this line:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
```

What that is doing is saying that when the `onreadystatechange` of the AJAX request changes, the anonymous function you are defining will run. This code is NOT being executed right away. It is waiting for an event to happen. This is an asynchronous process, so at the end of the function definition javascript will keep going, and if the state has not changed by the time it gets to `return status;` the variable `status` will obviously not have had time to set and your script would not work as expected. The solution in this case is to always `return false;` and then when the event fires (ie, the server responded with the PHP's script output) you can then determine the status and submit the form if everything is a-ok.

Answer (score 2):

It is *possible* to execute the send method synchronously, so request.responseText will be available immediately, but it's not normally a good idea. The request will hang the browser until it's complete.

To set the request as synchronous, set the third parameter to request.open to "false".

```
function checkUser() {
    var request;
    var status = false;

    //create xmlhttprequest object here [called request]

    var stu_id = document.getElementById("stu_id").value;
    var dName = document.getElementById("dName").value;
    var fileName = "check_user.php?dName=" + dName + "&stu_id=" + stu_id;
    request.open("GET", fileName, false);
    request.send(null);

    if (request.status === 200) {
        var resp = parseInt(request.responseText, 10);
        if(resp === 1) {
            alert("The display name has already been taken.");
            status = false;
        }
        else if(resp === 2) {
            alert("This student ID has already been registered");
            status = false;
        }
        else if(resp === 0) {
            status = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Request failed");
        status = false;
    }

    return status;
}
```

As I mentioned before though, **this is not a good idea**. It's almost always a better idea to do the request asynchronously so other code can run while you wait for a response. There's a reason **A**jax caught on instead of **S**jax.

Comment: An article that briefly explains why using XMLHttpRequest in synchronous mode is not such a good idea -  https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Synchronous_and_asynchronous_requests