# How to return a php value to the jQuery post

Tags: php, jquery

I just can't get my head around it. What do I need to write in my php file to return something to the `$.post` function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitToDatabase(uName, uComment)
    {
        $.post("write_something_to_mysql_b.php", {name: uName, comment: uComment});
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

This works, but there is no return value from the PHP file

Comment: This is nothing to do with PHP; this is the basic properties of the asynchronous nature of AJAX requests; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562412/return-value-from-function-with-an-ajax-call

Comment: Read up on [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). There are a ton of working examples.

Comment: use complete callback ... as noted read in docs how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// php:
$output['result']    = 'hello!!!';
echo json_encode($output); // json encode here
exit;

// jquery:
$.post(
"write_something_to_mysql_b.php",
{
    name : uName,
    comment : uComment
},
function(output) { // callback function to catch your php output
    // console.debug(output['result']);
    alert(output['result']);
    // output hello!!!
},
'json'); // json requirement here
```

`json` is just one of the possibilities to require data from backend side. Others are: xml, json, script, text, html. For each one of these formats you must to return data from backend in a suitable way. For example for `text` just `echo 'hello!!!; exit;`

Comment: @wubbewubbewubbe you're welcome. the other answers are good contributions too...

Comment: Some things just can't be guessed by someone who does not write pages on a regular basis. I've been studing http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ for hours.

Comment: @wubbewubbewubbe That's right, that's why we have SO! but the first is study by himself. Good!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure jQuery is hitting your PHP file. Use the developer tools in Chrome or [download Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) for Firefix, go to the 'Network' tab and when your JavaScript function `SubmitToDatabase()` is executed, check to see any network activity. If it's accessing the wrong PHP page, it'll show a 404.

If it's accessing the *correct* PHP page, check Firebug to see what value is returned. To return a value in PHP for a JavaScript call, you need to make sure you're using `echo` rather than `return`.

Comment: +1 for the important advice about debug with firebug to check php responses

Answer (score 1):

See [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). You must add a success function, if you want to do something with the PHP result

```
function SubmitToDatabase(uName, uComment)
{
    $.post("write_something_to_mysql_b.php", {name: uName, comment: uComment},
        function(data) { alert(data); });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the link to the life's water source :)